# Android Google Keep App Actionbar and Sticky View

Tags: android, android-actionbar, google-keep

I want to make android App that satisfies two option.

1. Blur Actionbar.
2. Quick Return View.(similar to Google Keep Quick Memo box.)

Two things completely satisfies App is Google Keep.

So, I reference for Open Source Library and Advice.

[> Quick Return View reference](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/scrolling-tricks/)
[> Blur ActionBar reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726214/transparent-actionbar-custom-tabcolor)
(SherlockActionbar do not use)

I tried to solve the problem in two ways. However, I have a problem.
Blur ActionBar use this option.
`<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>`
if use this option, main layout is hidden behind the actionbar.
so main layout started under status bar. which overlapped actionbar.
But use this option with Quick Return View reference,
Quick Return View also overlapped actionbar.

I want to see background through Blur actionbar. and
QuickReturnView show and hide under Action bar.
like Google Keep(Closer to the final goal.)

How can I do that? or Is another library that realized what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can add some padding to the top of your activity.

```
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

This adds padding equivalent to the height of the Action Bar.