# Navigation drawer below Actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-4.4-kitkat

Right now I just started a project in Android Studio with the NavigationBar as preconfigured in the template. Apparently it puts the navigation drawer behind the actionbar. Many questions you find want the navigation drawer on top of the actionbar, I would like to have it start below the actionbar. This is what I currently have:

[image: current situation]

eventually desired situation:

[image: desired situation]

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139846/navigation-drawer-below-transparent-actionbar) solution, but I think there should be an easier way.

Comment: the Navigation drawer should not be below the actionbar/toolbar, it is against the design guide lines

Comment: is it realy? https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: those are the old design guide lines, this is the updated one http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: Ok, well then I should talk to my designer about this ;)

Comment: Well Play Store App is like that :D I think that you can resolve your problem by adding in your activity theme style the line`< item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>` or change the theme to another one i guess

Comment: You're right and so does their hangout app. Ok, so the question still lives ;)

Comment: Your solution didn't work though, I'll have a look in the themes

Comment: @BartBurg did you find any solution. I am also struggling with this.

Comment: I don't give a damn what the Material Guidelines say - it's my app: I want it's GUI to look the best way it can look. Besides - guidelines are exactly that GUIDELINES.   ...and what exactly is the point of animating the Hamburger icon (changing it into an arrow on click / activation) if you are anyway going to hide it by overlaying the Nav Drawer on top of it?? The Google Design Devs obviously didn't think this one through carefully. So I am going to put my Nav Drawer BELOW the Actionbar - fullstop!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apply this attribute to your root viewgroup `android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure? Please see my answer one more time.

Comment: Almost now! it doesn't seem to take the notificationbar in this margin top.

Comment: Apparently, the shame is on me: in my style I had these 2 attributes: <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>

Comment: What do you mean by that? The status bar isnt taken in account when laying out views, but status bar does account for the total height of the screen

Comment: while this workaround works, the action bar is dimmed and darkened, where it should not be affected by these effects. Any ideas on how to fix it ?

Comment: @ralphspoon I have the same problem as you mentioned. I found the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26555224/1241783

Comment: @BartBurg: I am getting status bar size white space if I am giving `android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"`. can you plz help me out with this ?

Answer (score 7):

Try this
MainActivity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Put your content View here!" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi am using above code, its working pretty in SDK 23 and when same code execute on SDK 19 ActionbarTitle not showing.....   This is link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957481/android-navigation-drawer-ui-different-displayed-in-below-sdk-22?noredirect=1#comment67194862_39957481

Comment: Why don't you just use layout_below? Perhaps I missed a point?

Comment: ActionBarTitle doesnot exist on SDK19. It came after SDK21

Answer (score 0):

Along with Biu's answer

Add this line to your root view group too to take status bar/navigation bar into consideration

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Commenting incase anyone stumbles upon this thread again

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32133029)