# Android Navigation drawer UI different displayed in Below SDK 22

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-4.4-kitkat

[image]**Navigation drawer** working pretty in above **SDK 23** and same app execute on below SDK 22 its Title not appear in navigation drawer...It's showing as blank screen Actionbar title.

Below is my NavigationDrwer .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinateLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.smsapp.DashBoardActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!--
        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_dash_board"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    -->


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/white_image_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"

            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                layout="@layout/app_bar_dash_board"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/white_image_bg">


        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:name="com.smsapp.DashBoardActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_dash_board_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Do you use Material Design?

Comment: yes,am using material design.its working fine in my  device.Its having SDK 23.

Comment: Any links you followed?
Do you want to change the Action Bar title when navigating among the Fragments?

Comment: @sathishgadde give a color to the title and check it. Otherwise you have to post xml so we can further give any suggestion

Comment: Ok, am just uploaded xml,Please check it.

Comment: am also mentioned layout screen-shot...

Comment: It looks your toolbar is not shown on API level 19, I'll find try it on the device running 4.4 if i can find one.

Comment: Hi, sathish gadde, you can add "android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" to <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

Comment: Thank you, its working for me.