# Transparent ActionBar?

Tags: android

I want set Transparent ActionBar.
I have tried to edit xml but doesn't work . I am confused.
This is my Styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

can you make me an simple example for this?
See here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrrWl.png
I have tried this code but doesn't work..

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#330000ff")));
    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#550000ff")));
```

Logcat in Eclipse doesn't show a error... app crash

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13854832/1091466

Comment: Trasparent or fullscreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it before the `setContentView` not after it or youll get an error.

**solution:**

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000ff")));
    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000ff")));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //do it before this
```