# transparent action bar in fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to make a transparent action bar in particular fragment. I am able to make colour background in action bar. But when I try to make it as transparent or semi transparent by passing #80000000 as colour,it goes to black. Please help me how can I make it as transparent.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726214/transparent-actionbar-custom-tabcolor

Comment: i tried this solution. But this makes black background on action bar.

Comment: Tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23904522/3714897