# Make the transparent actionbar in fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, fragment

I've been searching on how to make transparent actionbar in fragment and no answer so far. So, the scenario is, I create an app using Navigation Drawer, each menu refer to same actionbar in `MainActivity`.

But I can't customize actionbar in transparent mode, like this [Transparent Actionbar: custom tabcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726214/transparent-actionbar-custom-tabcolor). In this:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#330000ff")));
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#550000ff")));
```

that code had to before `setContentView`, and as you know on the fragment we use `onCreateView` for the layout.

How can I achieve the transparent actionbar in fragment?

Comment: use the code in the parent activity to which your fragment is attached.

Comment: So is your code in `MainActivity` class in which your navigation drawer?

Comment: Why don't you put this code on Activity class or FragmentActivity class? I think it will be better.

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to make transparent Actionbar then you can do it by this way in Fragment's onCreateView

`getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#33000000")));`

Answer (score 0):

Use a Toolbar and use the following code to let it behave like Action bar

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

To include toolbar in your layout use the following.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:layout_width=”match_parent”
android:minHeight=”?attr/actionBarSize”
android:background=”?attr/colorPrimary” />
```

It is a lot easy to change transparency of Toolbar as compared to dealing with ActionBar

Once set you can deal with toolbar as any other view i.e. changing transparency/color dynamically is a lot easy for Toolbar

Comment: I can't use this, because the toolbar already have based on main Toolbar (set in main activity).

Comment: you can always use the getActivity() method and refer to the toolbar that is defined outside. You can also create a global variable to refer to toolbar