# How to make ActionBar Transparent?

Tags: android

[image]

Okay I want my ActionBar to look like the picture. I have 4 pages with all different picture. And when you scroll down I want the picture to be under the status bar and actionbar. How can I do this?

I tried to do it myself but the image appears like this.

[image]

Here is my app_bar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:elevation="0dp"
android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
android:transitionName="actionBar"
app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/toolbar_contentInset"
app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/CustomAppBar"
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />
```

My MainActivity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);;
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("");
```

Comment: This answer will help you to get transparent action bar. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13854832/2967875

Answer (score 0):

I see you've set your `Toolbar`'s color to transparent, good job! That's one step down, and one more to go.

You'd need to activate the `windowActionBarOverlay` mode to true, so that the space that were reserved for your `Toolbar` be gone and be filled with your content instead. To do this, either you specify it in your `style.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/action_bar_theme</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
</style>

<style name="action_bar_theme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#b3000000</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/action_bar_text</item>
</style>
```

..or alternatively, via your activity's `onCreate()`:

```
// Call this on your activity's onCreate() BEFORE YOU DO ANYTHING ELSE. 
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to implement the effect you want, only setting `Toolbar` overlay is not enough.

I implemented this before: `Toolbar` can be collapsed or expanded when contents are scrolled up or down. Here below are my codes, take a look at it first:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="me.danielpan.youtubelike.ProfileActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:paddingStart="0dp"
            app:statusBarScrim="?attr/colorAccent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_bg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@mipmap/profile_bg"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="3dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:rippleColor="@color/swipe_refresh_color_scheme_blue_1"
        app:borderWidth="3dp"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_plus"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/recycler_view"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I set `ThemeOverlay` to `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `Toolbar`. And this worked well: `Toolbar` is transparent at first, when contents are scrolled up, `Toolbar` becomes opaque and at last is in the color of my `ImageView` by using `Palette`.

Hope you'll be inspired by my codes, good luck~