# Make Android Action Bar transparent

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I'm trying to make my AppCompatActivity's Action Bar transparent. I'm looking for something [like this](https://lh4.ggpht.com/3dVMsp1ji8hN1fA3o4F6KTJpmdss7B1BiPK_oRLNP2v3IoIcEX6j9Sir1NgzUoe8NKQ=h900-rw) (from [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamma.scan)).

I've tried doing this:

> `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);`

But the only thing it does is making views go behind the action bar.

What can I do so that the text and the navigation drawer button are the only visible things on it?

Edit:
Here is my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="my.package.name"
            android:id="@+id/relLayout">

            <!-- My views are here -->

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the background color of the ActionBar? Please show your xml layout.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13854832/2341815

Comment: @jonas.koeritz I'm not really sure how I can make the color non-opaque. I edited in the xml layout.

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan You did it! I combined it with my previous code and used color #00ffffff and it does everything as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Try an ARGB value like #00000000 for fully transparent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For future readers:

I did it by setting the color of the action bar to a fully transparent color, `Color.TRANSPARENT`.
Here is my code:

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);

 getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: @AntónioPaulo No, it crashes the app, but #00000000 works

Comment: I used it today, i needed a button to have transparent background.

Comment: @AntónioPaulo I just tried it and it throws an "Invalid color" exception

Comment: Maybe works in buttons because it gives no color. Anyway good job figuring out the answer by yourself.

Comment: @AntónioPaulo: why don't you post and accept the answer which you figured out to solve the purpose.  believe me, it will help the community a lot :)

Comment: @srv_sud I did post my answer, but I can't accept it yet

Comment: @marti201: what error are you getting for accepting your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36723326/2615223

Comment: @srv_sud I can accept my own answer two days after posting it

Comment: @srv_sud I'm not the one that asked :)

Comment: @Antonio: that was for martin :)