# Android: how to align listView to bottom of custom actionBar?

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, alignment

I am following [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13726214/1827488) to make the `actionBar` "float" on top of an activity's contents so that my background image extends from top edge of screen instead of under the `actionBar`. However, now I need to align my `listView` to the bottom of the `actionBar` because `match_parent` now aligns the `listView` to the top edge.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve that in `xml` only? What would the `id` of the `actionBar` be so I can set `layout_below`?

I'm sure I can get/estimate the height of the `actionBar` in code to set the top margin of the `listView` accordingly but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution. Thanks

The `listView` activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_users"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_people_512"
        android:id="@+id/usersImageView"
        android:alpha="0.55"
        android:contentDescription="@string/backgroundImage"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/userListView"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

the custom `actionBar` layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainActionBar"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/mainActionBarSpacer"
        android:text="@string/mainActionBarSpacer"
        android:textColor="@color/colourTransparent"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mainActionBarSpacer"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mainActionBarSpacer"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/mainActionBarTitle"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colourActionBarText"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add layout_marginTop to your list view

```
android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
```