# Android: making a toolbar/actionbar invisible (transparent) but still functional

Tags: java, android, xml

How do I make the actionbar fully invisible but still functional. I should only see the icons I have and the title but the colour should be removed.

I tried like below:

```
toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0)
```

In my onCreate, but that just makes it white.

The XML code in my activity which sets the toolbar colour is here:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: share your xml file.

Comment: where is your actionbar code and xml ?

Comment: did you mean you want to set transparent background

Comment: @JamLis Then Set ActionBar layout background transparent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent Actionbar: custom tabcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13726214/transparent-actionbar-custom-tabcolor)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `setBackgroundDrawable` to transparent color

Same issue [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13854832/3664628)

Comment: Mines a toolbar, the answer there doesn't help me.  Any other recommendations ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#550000ff")));
```